# Looking for nice Javascript/jQuery code for displaying large tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I have an HTML table which may contain thousands of rows (number of columns is not a problem here).

I would like to be able to browse this table easily and be able to do the following:

- Decide how many rows will be presented
- Jump to the next/previous X number of rows
- Scroll the table using the scroll bars to any desired line
- Be able to customize/extend easily this Javascript/jQuery code

Has anyone seen something similar ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Not exactly [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402953/javascript-data-grid-for-millions-of-rows), but close. See also [slickgrid](http://wiki.github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/), [dojox.grid](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid), [extjs grid](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/buffer.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something like [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/).

It has the ability to:

- [Paginate](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination) your table.
- Jump to any page in the pagination.
- It currently cannot be **scrolled** to the desired location however ...
- It **is** easily extensible both via plugins and through its API.

It can also:

- Filter your table [And allows you to write custom filtering logic]
- Sort by any column or set of columns
- Pull from a multitude of data sources
- Use themes from Jquery UI (Which means it is also easy to roll your own.)

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery plugin might also meet your needs: [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

I use [flexigrid](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/flexigrid) but there is also [jgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6)