# Would this method cause lag of loading?

Tags: jquery

I am jQuery beginner, and currently i am doing some exercising, on every thing i learn - it's about couple of days i started doing jQuery course.

this is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nPcZJ/ example which i am working on,

**i was wondering is there a better way to achieve the same result?**

however a friend of mine told me if we have got 1000 questions displayed on a particular page and we want to show / hide the answer based on which questions was clicked.

**he said that would cause lack of loading the page...?**
it seems to be working perfectly with a few questions. 
but how about as he said 1000 questions..?
***is this really true if i have got 1000 questions that would cause the page not to load...?***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("dt").click(function(){
        var qst = $(this).parent().find('dd');
        $(qst).slideToggle();
    })
})

<dl>
     <dt>Q-1 What is your favorite scripting language ?</dt>
     <dd style="display: none">Ans - PHP, C++ </dd>      
</dl>

<dl>
    <dt>Q-2 What is your favorite IDE software ?</dt>
    <dd style="display: none">Ans - Aptana Studio 3, Dreamweaver</dd></dl>  
<dl>
    <dt>Q-3 Where are you from ?</dt>
     <dd style="display: none">Ans - I am from Russia</dd>  
</dl>

<dl>
    <dt>Q-4 Can you build small scripts - complex scripts ?</dt>
    <dd style="display: none">Ans - Yes, i can build small - complex scripts and from scratch</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: What do you mean by **lack of loading**? Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nPcZJ/1/ which seems to work fine. (1673 questions copy - pasted )

Comment: There is an easy way to answer this question: create a page with 1000 questions and see if it loads.

Comment: Do you mean lag? Maybe your friend means [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244322/large-dom-tree-slowing-down-jquery-click-events)

Comment: The more stuff you have on a page, the slower it loads. Does that answer your question?

Comment: `qst` is already a jquery object, no need to re-wrap it.  Just do `qst.slideToggle();`.  And I see no reason this code would cause loading issues.  Though I have no idea who would answer 1000 questions.  Anything will be slow if it gets large enough though.  If you really needed 1000 you should probably look into event delegation.

Comment: No, it wouldn't stop the page loading (though it might be slower to load/render). Incidentally, you don't have to wrap all the questions/answers into their own `dl` elements. I know you've said you've only just started learning, but the following works (even for multiple `dd` elements): http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nPcZJ/2/

Comment: Why do you have a separate definition list for every question?

Comment: @j08691: I wondered that, he's mentioned taking a class, so maybe they've not covered `nextUntil()`, or similar DOM traversal, yet?

Comment: thanks David, i have never seen .nextUntil() yet - but i will check it out on jQuery-Documention -

Answer (score 0):

you could prevent jQuery from traversing/searching in the large DOM for its parent and child by direct accessing the sibling `dd` from your `event.target.nextElementSibling`

```
$("dt").click(function(e){
    var qst=e.target.nextElementSibling; // which is same as $(this).next();
    //var qst = $(this).parent().find('dd');
    $(qst).slideToggle();
});
```

funny is, so its also possible to have shorter markup like

```
<dl>
    <dt>Q-1 What is your favorite scripting language ?</dt>
    <dd style="display: none">Ans - PHP, C++ </dd>
    <dt>Q-2 What is your favorite IDE software ?</dt>
    <dd style="display: none">Ans - Aptana Studio 3, Dreamweaver</dd></dl>     
</dl>
```

Comment: `<dl>` are definition lists, not list items.

Comment: `.nextUntil()` is not working correctly in this correct markup! but `$(this).next().slideToggle()` would do it very fine!

Comment: codelio, i just tried $(this).next().slideToggle() - it seems to be working fine,

Comment: well, this is true, a lot sugar in jQuery. but sometime native js is still very quick

Comment: i did't learn java-script, i just started learning jquery, however it's seems to be easy to learn, but still i need to learn java-script. or at least to get the basics of it.

Comment: dont worry, jQuery is javascript too!

Comment: oh yeah, i know that, it's java-script library, and it works all web browser