# high latency on event with jquery

Tags: jquery, performance, events, latency

my webapp is very slow and i start to investigate to find the reason. i think i find the problem, but not the solution. 
i analyzed with the console and you can see the result on the screen. the problem is everytime i click, there is a latency of almost 1000ms due to the event on the click. first, i think that was because of too many event click on the body in my code, but as you can see it's only between 0.3 and 1% if the total cost), very tiny compare to the 97.71% of n.event.handler.
so my question is where this latency come from?

in my code, there is a lot of :

```
 $('html').on('click', '.class', function(){ });
```

maybe too much?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can we possibly answer this without seeing the code being run in that click handler?

Comment: Try it with `$(document).on('click', '.class', function() {})`. It may not solve your problem, [but it's seemingly faster](http://jsperf.com/clickclclcl).

Comment: @DanLee you're testing the attachment of event handlers, not the calling.

Comment: how many of those do you have in your code? 10s? 100s? 1000s?

Comment: i think closest that 1000s than 100s

Comment: maybe you could try and use the unminified version of jquery, so that the function names make more sense? its hard to know what goes on in the functions `db` and `xb` which seem to be the culprits.

Comment: there is another question that might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576853/jquery-delegate-performance-on-the-click-event-on-large-lists-slows-down-if-yo?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you think you have too many of these:

```
$('html').on('click', '.class', function(){ });
```

you could try and refactor them into one handler:

```
$('html').on('click', function (e) {

  if (e.target.classList.contains('class')) {
       // e.target is the clicked element
      // do something here
  }

  if ($(e.target).is('class2')) {
     // you can wrap e.target into a jQuery object
     // the same way you wrap this.
     // do something else here
  }

});
```

Also, according to an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576853/jquery-delegate-performance-on-the-click-event-on-large-lists-slows-down-if-yo?rq=1), you should remove and add back those event handlers if you have lots of dynamically created targets.

Comment: thank for this, but in that case how can i get the $('this') from the on click?

Comment: "this.classList.contains('class')", it's don't work, he can't find the class. with the e target that you wrote before it's working, but in my function i use the $(this), it's really usefull for me.

Comment: Aw cr*p, it was correct before. $(e.target) then equals the $(this) you'he been using before