# A table with 5000 records takes more time or 5 tables with 1000 records take more time to render in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a table dynamically in Jquery. Can anyone suggest me if a table with 5000 records takes more time to render or 5 tables with 1000 records takes more time to render.

Comment: Well, why not try that? I'm sure results vary a lot on different browsers.

Comment: I'd say it depend on each browser. If you're concerned, I'd suggest paginating the output.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, yes its browser problem IE 9..pls anyone can help ..

Answer (score 1):

The defining factor here isn't the structure of the html, it is how you are creating it.

Adding one element at a time in a loop will be a lot slower than building up a string of html then setting the innerHTML property once.

Answer (score 0):

Single table with 5000 records will render faster (not significantly though), because overall html size will be smaller (less table,thead end etc tags) for one table rather than 5 tables.

But probably you don't want to output all data right away, so you might consider some table libraries like [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) or [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid). Also worth to mention that SlickGrid [supports million rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402953/javascript-data-grid-for-millions-of-rows/2569488#2569488).

Comment: I tried both of those but found no significant difference between those. Both are take almost same time to render.

Answer (score 0):

it is such a open ended question as there are hundreds of outher factors will effect the result. but basically 
one connection to table is going to be faster that 5 different connections to 5 different tables.

Comment: I know there are many dependencies on this. I was not asking about accuracy, I was asking which one is gonna render faster in an approximation scale.

Comment: i believe the users will not see the difference how you do it. we are talking about microseconds. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried both of those but found no significant difference between those. Both are take almost same time to render.

```
    function createTable() {

        var cols = 4;
        var rows = 1000;
        var table = $('<table></table>').appendTo('.divPlayersGrid');
        for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(table);
            for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {

                $("<td class='CustomTemplate'><div class='CustomTemplate'><input class='autoCompleteInput typeahead' type='text' placeholder='Enter player' /></div</td>").appendTo(row);
            }
        }           

    }
```

Call this method from document ready 5 times and mark the time it has taken. Then change the rows = 5000 in this method and call it once from the document ready and check the time it has taken to get rendered.

The difference is negligible user can not experience that I guess.