# Million rows tables (web development)

Tags: javascript, html, datagrid

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402953/javascript-data-grid-for-millions-of-rows) question that gives some options as to how to handle a lot of data to show in tables. My case is about 1,000,000 rows with 4 columns. I would need filtering options (text and dropdown) for all of the data. I have tried using MD Data tables, however when I have about 100k rows, the page loads for about 30 seconds and then just crashes. Options listed in the indicated question are very outdated and I am struggling to find something relevant. What are the modern options/frameworks for handling so much data without freezes?

Comment: You should split the table on multiple pages, maybe byhaving a pagination on the bottom of the table and load the data part by part. So first page will display like 50 rows, second page another 50 rows and so on.

Comment: This question will likely be closed for the same reason your referenced question was closed. I think the best response was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5581412), which queries why you think you need to analyse 1,000,000 rows of data in a single dataset at the client.

Comment: I have pagination in my current solution, but since all the data is downloaded at once, it still crashes. I think Google has a dozen people who can accomplish that, but I am alone out here :)

Comment: `needs to be done serverside` exactly.

Comment: my point was, I do not have time to reinvent the wheel, there must have been a solution already. And in fact, jqGrid still seems to be working. So I will probably go with that.