# mootools: How can i put 10,000 < div > tags in a single page

Tags: javascript, mootools, javascript-framework

I have developed an application in mootools. But its going little slow coz of number of tags it contains are almost 10,000. and every tag's structure is like:

```
<div style="float:left;padding:5px;margin: 6px;"> <!-- tag-1 -->
 <img src=""> <p>name</p> <p>Gender</p> <p>Mood</p> 
</div>
```

in following container

```
<div id="tags_container" style="overflow: scroll;height: 700px;">
 <div style="float:left;padding:5px;margin: 6px;"> <!-- tag-1 -->
  <img src=""> <p>name</p> <p>Gender</p> <p>Mood</p> 
 </div>
 <!-- tag-2 -->
   .  
   .
   .
 <!-- all tags one after another -->
</div>
```

i m showing these tags in rows and columns format ( 5 columns and 2000 rows). 
The id="tags_container" < div > has vertical scrollbar. but when i try to scroll down in that division to see further tags it scrolls little slow.

what should i do about it?

should i change the implementation method from < div > tags to < table > tag?

what are the options to make it any faster?

In few previous questions, i was advised not to use those many tags in one single document but there is gonna be those many tags so what should i do about it.?

Comment: 10k tags will be somewhat slow, especially depending on the end user machine. One thing I can say is do not switch to tables. They take longer to render than divs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297626/) before. Use more CSS classes and fewer elements, and remove **everything** unnecessary (like comments). Though the data was tabular in nature, I found it *much* easier to create a pixel-perfect layout using `<div>`s.

#### Markup

```
<div class="cell">
 <img src=""> <p>name</p> <p>Gender</p> <p>Mood</p> 
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div.cell {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 6px;
}
```

If possible, it may also be quicker to use [CSS spriting](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) for the images, rather than 10k *more* elements for the images. Something like:

#### Markup

```
<div class="cell" style="background-position: 0px 0px;">
    <p>name</p> <p>Gender</p> <p>Mood</p> 
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div.cell {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 6px;
    background-image: url(path/to/sprite);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

---

***Edit*** If you need to do any sort of DOM manipulation of these elements, I recommend loading all of them up into a JS array — **once** — and then accessing them by index from the array. Repeatedly querying the DOM for the same elements will wreck performance.

If possible, also remove the `<p>` elements within each `<div>`. If you've got 10k `<div>` elements, each containing 3 `<p>`s, then you're really working with a minimum of 40k elements.

**That's a lot of DOM, baby.**

If you can figure out how to get the same layout removing even just 1 or 2 `<p>`s from each `<div>`, you're instantly down to 20k or 30k elements.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a table? It looks like you're trying to build a table with divs.

Comment: coz that will introduce one extra tag per row "< tr > < / tr >".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a tabular document to me.  Why not use a table?

Note that even with a table you may have some trouble, but I suspect it will be faster.

You should also consider using a class for your styling, rather than doing it manually for each row.

Comment: Tables will incur more markup and actually be slower. Tables do render slower and will also cause more DOM traversal incurring even more speed loss.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the exact reason tables were created in the first place - tabular style data. Any reason you aren't using tables already?

Comment: coz that will introduce one extra tag per row "< tr > < / tr >".

Answer (score 0):

A large amount of tabular data renders fastest if you break it up into separate tbodies, and set table-layout to fixed. Keep all the style info out of the html and in a style element or linked stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to show all 10,000 rows on the page at once?   Perhaps you could look at implementing the [ScrollSpy plugin](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy-load) developed by David Walsh.  This will allow you to load a smaller initial record set then access more records when required.